# Not enough space to cache broadcast in memory

Tags: scala, apache-spark, azure-hdinsight

I use HDInsight and I run an iterative algorithm with Spark over a binary tree. I broadcast in each node and execute only one Action "isEmtpy()" in the root node. 
For a large graph I run into the following error:

```
17/05/08 00:05:36 WARN MemoryStore: Failed to reserve initial memory threshold of 1024.0 KB for computing block broadcast_1066 in memory.
17/05/08 00:05:36 WARN MemoryStore: Not enough space to cache broadcast_1066 in memory! (computed 384.0 B so far)
17/05/08 00:05:36 INFO MemoryStore: Memory use = 479.2 KB (blocks) + 0.0 B (scratch space shared across 0 tasks(s)) = 479.2 KB. Storage limit = 564.2 KB.
17/05/08 00:05:36 ERROR Utils: Exception encountered
java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at org.apache.spark.util.collection.PrimitiveVector$$anon$1.next(PrimitiveVector.scala:58)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.memory.PartiallyUnrolledIterator.next(MemoryStore.scala:697)
    at org.apache.spark.util.CompletionIterator.next(CompletionIterator.scala:30)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast$$anonfun$readBroadcastBlock$1$$anonfun$2.apply(TorrentBroadcast.scala:178)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast$$anonfun$readBroadcastBlock$1$$anonfun$2.apply(TorrentBroadcast.scala:178)
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:146)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast$$anonfun$readBroadcastBlock$1.apply(TorrentBroadcast.scala:178)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryOrIOException(Utils.scala:1276)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast.readBroadcastBlock(TorrentBroadcast.scala:174)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast._value$lzycompute(TorrentBroadcast.scala:65)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast._value(TorrentBroadcast.scala:65)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast.getValue(TorrentBroadcast.scala:89)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.Broadcast.value(Broadcast.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:72)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:47)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:86)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:274)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
17/05/08 00:05:36 INFO ExecutionMemoryPool: TID 84793 waiting for at least 1/2N of on-heap execution pool to be free
```

My broadcast variables arent large... I run the application on 5 worker. this error occurs in an executor.
Thanks!

Comment: try setting the option --driver-memory 4G

Comment: this error occurse on an executor. Each executor has 5g memory. I wonder, why the error occurse on a broadcast.

Comment: Yes, (i dont why yet), but it seems related to driver memory.